# Two store() methods, one doesn't work (Call to undefined method save())

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

One of two similar store methods doesn't work. Could you clarify this for me?

#### Relations

- A Team hasMany Users <> A User belongsTo a Team
- A User hasMany Characters <> A Character belongsTo a User

#### Working Code (CharacterController)

```
public function store()
{
    $fighters = Fighter::pluck('name')->toArray();
    $this->validate(request(), [
        'name' => 'required|min:3|max:25|alpha_num|not_in:'.Rule::notIn($fighters).'unique:characters',
        'fighter' => 'required|in:'.Rule::in($fighters),
    ]);
    auth()->user()->characters()->save(new Character([
        'name' => request('name'),
        'fighter' => request('fighter'),
    ]));
    return redirect()->route('character.index');
}
```

#### Not Working (TeamController)

```
public function store()
{
    $this->validate(request(), [
        'name' => 'required|min:3|max:25|alpha_num|unique:teams',
    ]);
    auth()->user()->team()->save(new Team([
        'name' => request('name'),
        'fame' => 0,
    ]));
    return redirect()->route('team.index');
}
```

#### Questions

1. Why is the same method not available? Is it relation stuff?
2. Is the create method better? Should I try to use it?

Thought I know what I'm doing, now it turns out I don't... 
Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`team()` is a `belongsTo` relation, you probably have a team_id col in your user table which you want to associate with the team.

```
public function store()
{
    $this->validate(request(), [
        'name' => 'required|min:3|max:25|alpha_num|unique:teams',
    ]);

    // create and save team
    $team = new Team([
        'name' => request('name'),
        'fame' => 0,
    ]);
    $team->save();

    // associate current authenticated user with team (set foreign key) and save user
    auth()->user()->team()->associate($team)->save();

    return redirect()->route('team.index');
}
```

Comment: Great. Let's pray I can save this to my brain aswell! Seems you know what's going on. Does the CharacterController is looking good enough with all the chainings?

Comment: it's basically 1 chain $user->characters()->doStuff(). It was created to allow chaining, just try and keep your code readable.